# How can i put this container to fill the second part of homePage

Tags: flutter

[image]I have the home page and inside it I put a HomeMenu component but it is not filling the entire screen. I tried to tidy it up a few ways but it didn't work, can you help me?

The HomeMenu is the part gray
i'll leave the code of both

HomePage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:metroguia/pages/home/components/home_menu.dart';
import 'home_header.dart';

class bodyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const bodyHome ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            HomeHeader(),
            HomeMenu(),
          ],
      ),
    );
   }
}
```

HomeMenu:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:metroguia/pages/home/components/fav_routes.dart';
import 'package:metroguia/pages/home/components/title_home.dart';
import '../../../constants/colors.dart';

class HomeMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100),
            child: Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: menu,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(16)
                    )
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 25),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 5,
                              width: 78,
                              color: textNavegation,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 244,
                        height: 50,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(66),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                blurRadius: 4.0,
                                offset: Offset(0.0, 3.0)
                            )
                          ]
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20,
                              vertical: 15
                            ),
                            prefixIcon: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                color: blueDetails,
                              ),

                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 20,
                              ),
                            ),

                            hintText: "Pesquise o seu destino",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: textMain,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                letterSpacing: -0.4
                            )
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                     TitleHome(),
                     FavoritesRotas()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

I tried to use Expanded or SizedBox setting a value to heigth but ends up giving error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded can't/doesn't work in Column layout. I believe a Flex() widget can support expanded. Or wrap your HomeMenu widget with a container and perform a MediaQuery.of(context).size.height to get the screen height your widget should fill.

Comment: Do you can show me on the code?

Comment: oh my mistake, Expanded do work columns. However have you tried remvoing the MainAxisAlignment.center on all of the columns?
   
   `SizedBox(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
       child: Column(),
    ),`